# Where is the bug in this C code?

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I am very new in programming. I wanted to write a program to implement queue with array (circular queue). I think the inserting & deleting element from queue functions are correct ,but there is some problem in display function. When queue is full, if I try to insert more element it doesn't show "QUEUE FULL" as per function, it shows some garbage values alongside elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define m 3   // maximum size of array
int Q[m];
int f=-1,r=-1,s;        //f=front,r=rear,s=rear in another term for finding wheather is 

queue full


int enQueue(int item){
    s = (r+1)%(m+1);
    if(f == s)
        printf("\nQUEUE FULL"); 
    else{
        Q[s] = item;
        r = s;
    }

return 0;
}


int deQueue(){
    int item;
    if(f == r)
        printf("\nQUEUE UNDERFLOW");
    else{   
        f = (f+1)%(m+1);
        item = Q[f];
        Q[f] = NULL;
    }

return 0;
}

void displayQueue(){
    int i;
    if(f == r) 
        printf(" \n The queue is empty\n");
    else {
        printf("\nQUEUE IS : \n");
        for(i=f+1; i<=s; i++) {
            printf("%d\t", Q[i]);
        }
        printf("\n\n********************************************");
    }

}



int main(){
    int item,i,j;

    while (1){
        printf("\n\nENTER ITEM TO INSERT : ");
        scanf("%d", &item);

        enQueue(item);
        displayQueue();
    }

 _getch();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you use a debugger?

Comment: Why `m+1` is used instead of `m` to divide the number? There are risk of accessing out-of-range of array!

Comment: I wrote this code in Visual Studio 12 @ MikeCAT

Comment: maybe you can focus us and write what is the bug? Maybe you can show the expected result vs. what you get?

Comment: When queue is full, if I try to insert more element it doesn't show "QUEUE FULL" as per function, it shows some garbage value

Comment: Visual Studio *is* a debugger. And please improve your question by describing exactly what the expected output is and what the actual output is (not just "there is some problem").

Comment: `f` won't be updated in other than `deQueue()`, so `f == s` in `enQueue()` won't be true unless `deQueue()` is executed or memory contents are broken by out-of-range write.

Comment: First, fix the program so that it compiles cleanly with warnings enabled. Then you can ask questions about the program's run-time behavior.

Comment: What do you mean with `Q[f] = NULL;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has quite a few problems. This reply deals only with what's within the question scope. Hope it can help.

```
int enQueue(int item){
   if(r+1 >= m)   //check against queue size first...
        printf("\nQUEUE FULL"); 
   else{
        s = (r+1)%(m);
        Q[s] = item;
        r = s;
    }
return 0;        //the return value part could be written better...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `if` condition in the `enQueue()` function.

`f` is -1 which is not getting change throughout the program, and `s` will never be -1 so the condition will never work out.

Change the if condition to from `s == f` to `s==m`, that is.

```
if(s == m)
    printf("Queue is full");
```

Run the program again.
I have tested it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try a new count variable so that you can track the number of elements in the array present a time

```
initialize the count to 0 as global
if enque 
check count for the overflow 
 if not
  add element and increase the count
if deque
check count for the underflow
 if not
  delete the element and decrese the count
```